# Display style can't be removed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have something strange going on and I hope someone can help me out, as I am fairly new to this.

The style="display: none" is showing up when I am looking in the developer mode in Firefox, but I don't want this style any more and need the item to be displayed. However when I am looking in the source code, I can't find the style="display: none" anywhere. So it is impossible for me to remove it.

Here is the code from the developer mode on the website:

```
<tr class="recurring-totals" style="display: none">
                <th colspan="2">Recurring totals</th>
            </tr>
```

And here is the source code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$display_th = true;

?>

            <tr class="recurring-totals">
                <th colspan="2"><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring totals', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
```

I am lost on where to look next and how to make the item visible again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The PHP file does not include an option for the inline css. I guess there is a javascript setting it.

Comment: If code looks different between "View Source" and "Inspect", you should always suspect JavaScript. You might be able to fix this (and break something else) by change either this class or the parent's class/ID.

Comment: your javascipt could be hiding the element. try with javascript disabled in the browser developer tools to check

Comment: Thank you guys, it was indeed Javascript hiding and causing it to hide!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your css file: `tr.recurring-totals { display: block !important; }`